# How to commit the same commits after reverting, while preserving commit information?

Tags: git

Say I do the following operations:

```
git init
touch initial && git add initial && git commit -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b A
touch test_1 && git add . && git commit -m "Commiting test 1"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        NORMAL
touch test_2 && git add . && git commit -m "Commiting test 2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        NORMAL
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff A
git revert -m 1 head
```

Now, after reverting those commits, something changes and I decide I want those commits again.

I can't do `git merge A` again because those commits are already in the branch.

I'd rather not do `git revert head` because then when someone runs `git blame`, they'll see `Revert "Revert "Merge branch 'A'""` which isn't particularly helpful. So I'd like the commit messages / bodies of the original commits to be preserved.

My hack was to run git rebase on `A` and amend the message of the first commit slightly, so the hashes of the commits are updated and I can merge again, but there must be a better way to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the revert:

```
git revert <commit sha of the revert>
```

Another option is to cherry pick a diff between two commits:

```
git cherry-pick master...dev
```

Finally you can also put diff into patch then apply it:

```
git diff commit1 commit2 > some.patch
git apply some.patch
```

Comment: I'd rather not revert the revert (see the question for why). Can you be more specific in how I'd use cherry-pick? Pretty sure that I can't do `git cherry-pick master...A`, since the last commit is a merge which cherry-pick doesn't like.

Comment: I have added the patch option, maybe you can use that to create a patch between the commits you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Reverting the revert is far more informative than having it change underneath your feet suddenly and without explanation through a rebase.

Remember:

- `revert` retains the commit information and effectively creates a reverse-patch, which is why Git sees the merged branch and refuses to merge it again until the revert is reverted.
- `rebase` ***removes history.***  You do not want to remove history unless it is necessary.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't run rebase on master. I ran it on A and merged A back into master after.

Comment: That's even worse.  It's going to make a mess of your Git history when revert had already introduced its own mess.  You're better sticking with revert.

Comment: Why is that even worse? The only git history I'm messing up is on the feature branch, which doesn't need a consistent history.

Comment: I still feel like, just to be sure that a good flow is in your head, that you should look to revert the revert instead of overwriting history.  This feels like a bad habit waiting to hit the workflow primetime, and I'd rather you understood what you were getting into before applying rebases.

Comment: To that point, you may be only messing up the history of your one branch, but in your example, *you've already merged that branch in*.  You don't want to do repeated rebase and merges to another branch like that, since it means you can't cleanly determine when your code was introduced.

Comment: Git history should be consistent so that you as a developer or others as consumers of the Git logs can actually tell what's going on with the code base.  This makes troubleshooting problematic releases or diagnosing issues easier (and also makes `git bisect` actually work well).

Answer (score 0):

It's true that tripping through a series of revert-reverts is obnoxious.

(It gets worse, during one sprint there was a code path that had, I think, a total of six levels of revert, that I saw go by.  Fortunately that was on a branch not meant for release.)

A revert, by default, records the hash ID of the commit it's reverting, so you can simply explicitly cherry-pick the original commit (and perhaps edit the message to note that it's being re-imported after having been reverted).  This can even be done for merges by supplying the `-m` argument, although there is an occasional edge case here (so be careful with the result).

Alternatively—and a bit safer—revert the reversion of the merge, but then edit the commit message to put in more information.  You can either use `-e`/`--edit` (which is the default anyway) with the `git revert` command, or `git commit --amend` the revert-of-reversion commit to copy it to a new and improved one with the improved commit message.